# Get just the base domain with PHP?

Tags: php, dns, subdomain

Is there any general way to get just the base domain (without subdomain)? For example, with the following URLs (assuming no fore-knowledge about what the domains or subdomains might be...)

```
www.example.com
mysub.example.com
example.com

www.example.co.uk
example.co.uk
xyz.example.co.uk
```

For the first three, I'd like to get just "example.com", for the last, "example.co.uk", with a function that could be used in any website/server/domain.

Is it possible?

Comment: Except `example.co.uk` is a subdomain of `co.uk`

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
$arr = explode(".", $str);
echo $arr[count($arr)-2];
```

with additional error handling

But the thing with .co.uk and so on is very difficult and sometimes new tlds are released

I found this: [Get root DNS entry from php server; get domain name without www, ect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375647/get-root-dns-entry-from-php-server-get-domain-name-without-www-ect?rq=1)

You also should find something in the net